# jQuery Drop Event is propagating to below elements (for a floating bar)

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-droppable

I am designing a form builder in which there is a floating bar which contains all the form elements. Below this there is droppable section where user can drop the elements. It works fine.

The problem is when I scroll down, the floating bar comes over the droppable section. Now I drag a element and leave them inside the div from where they were dragged instead of dropping into the droppable section still the drop event of the "droppable section" fires!